# How to automatically zoom buttons and everything in Qt on qWidget.showFullScreen()?

Tags: c++, qt, pyqt

I want to resize everything when i show it in full screen automatically keeping aspect ratio. How can i do it. i use PyQt4 but if you know of C++ then also please tell me.

Hope the code will be not more than 2-3 lines.
Thanks

Comment: Use QML, widgets does not support scaling.

Comment: @DmitrySazonov This is false. See [this Qt blog](http://blog.qt.io/blog/2013/04/25/retina-display-support-for-mac-os-ios-and-x11/) for early details, and [this blog on Qt 5.6](https://blog.qt.io/blog/2016/01/26/high-dpi-support-in-qt-5-6/) for more recent improvements.

Comment: Are you trying to get *everything* to scale, including font sizes, etc?

Comment: @JonHarper You wrong. I'm not talking about support of different DPI. It is not, what is requested in questions. Ahmad wants dynamic scaling on custom multiplier.

Comment: @DmitrySazonov Ah, I see what you mean. Yeah, QML looks like the only (easy) solution if he's scaling everything, including fonts and icons.

Comment: @JonHarper Yes i want to do for everything

Comment: How can i use QML (Actually i am new to PyQt4) any tutorial page?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you've implemented static layouts with fixed widget sizes and positions in your dialogs/windows. In order to resize the widgets with the window, what you need to do is using [dynamic layouts](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html). You best use [*Qt Designer*](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtdesigner-manual.html) for the dialog design, else setting up any non-trivial layout can get rather toilsome.

Comment: I have already made my app i cant re code it, it will be about 5000 lines.